# Creating a docker container from a jar file with depedencies

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, maven, executable-jar

I have created a java application that parses CSV data into a json file. I have packaged it out into its respective jar file and eclipse has also created a lib folder containing all my dependant jar files.
[Here is the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxJc1.png) as you can see it also contains the data.csv file i am parsing.

Now i am trying to create a docker image that will run my jar file, the only problem is i am unsure of how to sturcture my docker file to contain the jar file, and the dependencies (including the csv file) also. Here is the current docker file i have:

```
FROM openjdk:12-alpine
COPY RunnableApplication/CsvParser_lib /run/dependency-jars
COPY ./RunnableApplication/CsvParser.jar /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "CsvParser.jar"]
```

Is there a way to add the csvParser_lib folder aswell as the data.csv file to the container so i can run the jar file with its dependencies? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ii am not quite sure I can follow. You alread copied the libs to the docker container. You need to add the folder `/run/dependeny-jars` to the classpath when starting the application. Also, what is left to do is copy over the `csv`-file you want to parse. The structure so far looks good, you copy the libraries before your application, creating a separate layer for the libraries (which is good!). If the `csv`-file changes regularly, I would adivce to copy it after the application. Otherwise, copy before you copy the application.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me! may I ask how I add that folder to the classpath? I have also added another line to copy the csv file into the container, so my dockerfile now contains this  COPY RunnableApplication/data.csv /usr/app/

Comment: "*may I ask how I add that folder to the classpath?*" - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html